# Declaring multiple arguments configurations of a function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can accept one parameter and it can have multiple types.

```
    getItems(user: User | null = null) {
        if (user instanceof User) return getItemsOfUser(user);
        getAllItems();
    }
```

In order to increase readability I wonder if it is possible to have a notation like this one:

```
    getItems(user: null)
    getItems(user: User) {
        if (user instanceof User) return getItemsOfUser(user);
        getAllItems();
    }
```

The logic in this layer is supposed to receive a generic case and call the more specific service functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are seeking function overload
See : [how-to-overload-functions](https://dev.to/zirkelc/how-to-overload-functions-in-typescript-22c3)